# Does Deezer android SDK support arabic configuration?

Tags: deezer

In my android application, I use the Deezer SDK to play tracks, using the com.deezer.sdk.player.TrackPlayer class.
When my android device is configured in many languages (english, german, french, greek, chinese, hebrew, ...), the Deezer player works perfectly to play a track.
When I configure my android device with arabic language, the track is not played.
That is the reason why I wonder if the Android Deezer TrackPlayer is supposed to work with arabic configuration.
This is the Deezer SDK version number I use : 0.10.16.

Comment: That's really strange as the SDK in itself does nothing based on the device's language. Does this also happen with the sample application that comes with the SDK?

Comment: I have just made a test with the sample application. I fails with arabic language as for my application. I get error toasts when I try to play a track or a playlist. But it works for other languages.

Comment: I'll take a look into it as soon as possible

Comment: Indeed, the issue is when generating the API urls, it uses the arabic language and so api.deezer.com/album/42 becomes api.deezer.com/album/٤۲. This will be fixed in the next version

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Do you have an idea of when the next version will be released ?

Comment: I don't have a date yet, but I'll try to make it happen as soon as possible

Comment: I have just downloaded the 0.10.17 Deezer android SDK beta version. I only find one libdeezer.so file for the armeabi architecture in the aar file. Is this SDK beta version incomplete ?

Comment: indeed there was a glitch in our build script, we'll update the new version asap